# How can I change the text "Select all" on my dxDataGrid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devexpress, dx-data-grid

I'm using dxDataGrid with AngularJS and I'd like to change the text "Select All"

[image]

I was looking for the solution in the documentation and I think that it is here but I cannot change it:

```
headerFilter: {
    visible: true,
    texts: {
      cancel: $i18n.translate("lbl_cancel"),
      emptyValue: $i18n.translate("lbl_empty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
       Globalize.addCultureInfo("es", {
                        calendars: {
                            standard:{
                                days:{
                                    names: [$i18n.translate("lbl_monday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_tuesday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_wednesday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_thursday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_friday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_saturday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_sunday")],
                                    namesAbbr: [$i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_monday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_tuesday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_wednesday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_thursday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_friday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_saturday"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_sunday")]
                                },
                                months: {
                                    names: [$i18n.translate("lbl_january"), $i18n.translate("lbl_february"), $i18n.translate("lbl_march"), $i18n.translate("lbl_april"), $i18n.translate("lbl_may"), $i18n.translate("lbl_june"), $i18n.translate("lbl_july"), $i18n.translate("lbl_august"), $i18n.translate("lbl_september"), $i18n.translate("lbl_october"), $i18n.translate("lbl_november"), $i18n.translate("lbl_december"), ""],
                                    namesAbbr: [$i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_january"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_february"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_march"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_april"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_may"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_june"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_july"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_august"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_september"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_october"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_november"), $i18n.translate("lbl_abbr_december"), ""]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            "dxList-selectAll": $i18n.translate("lbl_select_all"),
                            "dxCollectionWidget-noDataText": $i18n.translate("lbl_no_data_to_display")
                        }
                    });                       
       Globalize.culture("es");
```